# How to display Admob on the top of my Layout using XML on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I'm kind of struggling with the new AdMob. **I want my ad to display on the top** as on the image below:

[image: a]

I'm doing what the google documentation says but **the ad always appears on the bottom** (after all my other views)...

***Notes:***

- *It displays it properly (at the top of the screen) on the Eclipse's XML preview but not on my emulator/physical devices.*
- *It concerns all my XML files I have done since I use AdMob, not especially this one.*

I tried many different techniques and did a lot of researches but all the questions and answers I find (on SO and other websites) concern the "old" AdMob display (pre winter 2013).

Here is on of my XML file, **the interesting part is certainly on the top, after the com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView it's only a "grid" made in LinearLayout followed by one bigger button**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="MY HIDDEN AD UNIT ID" />


 <!-- The part below is a grid made of 4 Linear Layouts displaying buttons -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button3"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="3"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button4"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="4"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button5"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="5"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button6"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="6"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button7"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="7"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button8"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="8"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button9"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="9"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button10"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="10"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button11"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="11"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button12"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="12"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button13"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="13"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button14"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="14"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button15"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="15"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button16"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="16"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonErase"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="@string/erase"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I could change my LinearLayout to a Relative one, if you think it's a solution, but I find the LinearLayout easier to play with.

My question is, of course: **What should I change to display my Ad at the top of the screen instead of at the bottom of the screen ?** What didn't I get here ? *All documentation you have is welcomed, I just can't find enough resources/SO posts to answer my question as it's a "new version" of AdMob (as I said earlier)*.

Comment: For sure I have a solution with Relative Layout, they are actually more convenient and flexible than Linear ones.

Comment: Do you use RelativeLayouts for most of your cases ? Are LinearLayouts a bit "depreciated" (to the android developers point of view) and only useful in some circumstances ? Or it depends of personal preferences/habits ?Thank you for your answer by the way, it fixed my issue :)

Comment: I think `LinearLayout` can be ok for simple and "linear" layouts, but once it gets a little complex, you need too add many different Linear Layouts to get what you need. I switched most of my layouts from Linear to Relative because this way the XML was shorter and at the same time faster to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ready to switch to `RelativeLayout` (that should not be long), here is the beginning of what should be your new XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="XXXXX" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/search_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/adview" />
```

The most important is to add `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` for the AdView element. Then just be sure that all the other elements are below this one (using `layout_below`).